# Mocking Router Subscriptions for Jasmine tests in Angular 6

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a pair of failing unit tests for compiling my components.  In either case, it is due to my code attempting to reference either the `router.events` or `router.params`:

> router.params

```
ngDoCheck() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(
     () => {
       if (this.router.url !== this.url && this.levelOneState === 'maximized') {
         this.levelOneState = 'minimized';
       }
       this.url = this.router.url;
     }
   )
 }
```

> router.events

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    find(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.setCurrentNav();
  });
```

I have set up my test(s) like so:

```
let router;
router.events = of(new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/', 'http://localhost:4200/'));

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
      { provide: Router, useValue: router }
    ]
  })
    .compilecomponents();
}));
```

However when I run my jasmine tests, I get an error saying that I 'cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'.  I can't seem to find any answers or guidance to know where I might be going wrong.  Can anyone provide some information on how I can set this up differently?

Comment: This is covered extensively in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#routing-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `RouterStub` class and initialize the values to mock `Router` in tests.

```
class RouterStub {
   config = [];
   events = of({});
   params = of({});
   url = '';
   resetConfig() {}
   navigate() { }
}
```

You can mock the values (url, params etc) as per your use in TestClass.
Use it in the TestBedConfiguration:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
           TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           declarations: [
            ...
             { provide: Router, useValue: new RouterStub()}
          ]
        })
        .compilecomponents();
       }));
```

Comment: I created a mock RouterStub class, and use it in my `useValue` for Router.... but I am still getting these undefined errors.

Comment: Check if you are subscribing to `ActivatedRoute` or `Router` in component. and Mock as you need.

Comment: Actually this solved one of the undefines, and the other is still failing, but this looks to solve my initial problem.

Comment: Yes another dev on my team named the activatedRoute variable as 'route' as well as having a router called router.  Mistake on my part your answer is correct.